# how to access distribution archive

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle project that posts a configuration tree to a server endpoint

```
plugins {
    id 'base'
    id 'distribution'
}

distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            from('backends') { into '/backends' }
            from('trees') { into '/trees' }
        }
    }
}

task uploadConfigurations(type: Exec, dependsOn: distZip) {
    group = "upload"
    description = "some description"
    def zipFile = distZip.archiveFile.get().asFile.absolutePath
    executable "curl"
    args "-v", "localhost:8080/my/resource/path", "--data-binary", "@$zipFile"
}
```

While the solution is effective, I suspect there is a more elegant solution to access the archive file than my cumbersome

```
def zipFile = distZip.archiveFile.get().asFile.absolutePath
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, whether or not a solution is elegant is opinion-based, but I'm gonna suggest a solution that in addition provides some more advantages:

```
task uploadConfigurations(type: Exec) {
    group = "upload"
    description = "some description"
    inputs.files(distZip)
    executable "curl"
    doFirst {
        def zipFile = inputs.files.singleFile.absolutePath
        args "-v", "localhost:8080/my/resource/path", "--data-binary", "@$zipFile"
    }
}
```

The first change adds a Gradle feature called *incremental build support*. By registering the task `distZip` as an input of the task `uploadConfigurations`, the dependency between the task is registered implicitly (no need for `dependsOn`). In addition, Gradle will perform an up-to-date check and skip the execution of task `uploadConfigurations` if the output of task `distZip` did not change. The actual file path can be resolved via the task inputs as well.

The second difference is the `doFirst` closure to set the `args` of the `Exec` task. It ensures that the actual path of the file is resolved as late as possible, allowing other parts of the build script to change the value once the task `uploadConfigurations` is configured. To check this limitation of the current build script, insert the line `distZip.archiveFileName = 'myDist.zip'` after the task definition.

Finally, another advantage of the snippet above is the single point that defines a coupling between the two tasks (`inputs.files(distZip)`). In the current script, you need to change both the task dependency and the resolution of the file name.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. But future readers should know that task execution is only skipped, when both inputs **and ouputs** did not change. The above task is considered out-of-date and will be exectuted even when inputs did not change. To achieve _true incremental build support_ one must declare explicetly that the task does not have any output like so `outputs.files()`